# Need help on JBPM workflow Automation

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jbpm, continuous-deployment

I am a new bee to JBOSS BPM and started researching on Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment (CI&CD) of BPM workflow

Here is the workflow that we have come up with for CI&CD in our project.

1. Developer pushes code to GIT repository.
2. Jenkins pulls code from GIT, builds code and publishes to NEXUS repository.
3. JBOSS FUSE pulls binaries from NEXUS and deploys them.
4. Once FUSE deploys the code, we can view output accordingly through REST services.

Manual steps followed to import the project into BPM suite.

1. Open http://localhost:8080/business-central/ with valid credentials
2. Authoring tab -> Administration -> Clone Repository - > provided project details with GIT repo -> Clone.
3. Authoring tab -> Artifact Repository ->  Upload project jar.
4. Authoring tab -> Project Authoring -> Select created project in project explorer.
5. Open Project Editor -> Build & Deploy.
6. Register a server and create a container.

Since, we had followed a manual process so far, we have a requirement to automate this process now. Can anyone please suggest feasible options on how to automate workflow in BPM in order to achieve CI&CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, almost all manual steps you have described can also be executed using REST API. [Knowledge Store REST API](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html-single/Development_Guide/index.html#sect-Knowledge_Store_REST_API) allows you to clone your project, [Deployment REST API](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html-single/Development_Guide/index.html#sect-Deployment_REST_API) to deploy it and [REST API for Intelligent Process Server Administration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html-single/User_Guide/index.html#The_REST_API_for_Managing_the_Realtime_Decision_Server) to create servers and containers. The only thing that I am not sure about is uploading project JAR.

But I wonder why you upload your project to Business Central if you do not modify it there in any way. It seems you use KIE Server to run your processes (according to step 6) so you just need to put your project to the Maven repository where KIE Server can find it.

Comment: Sorry for delaying my response. 

This was what I was looking for exactly. Perfect reply !! 

Yes, we are using KIE server.
 I have tried few remote APIs ( Maven compile, install, deploy, displaying list of containers, start and stop scanner) and they are working fine. But I am stuck at the following. 

1. Starting and stopping a container already existing. 
2. Upgrade the container.

Comment: I assume you use KIE Server in [managed mode](http://mswiderski.blogspot.cz/2015/09/unified-kie-execution-server-part-3.html), right? If you want to know how to start and stop containers, have a look at the last two REST calls in section [9.7.1. Managed Intelligent Process Server Environment](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html-single/User_Guide/index.html#idp97644016) of the User Guide.

Comment: There is also an endpoint which allows you to change the container configuration but it seems it is missing in the documentation. Look at [this method](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/6.4.x/kie-server-parent/kie-server-controller/kie-server-controller-rest/src/main/java/org/kie/server/controller/rest/RestSpecManagementServiceImpl.java#L259) in the source code.

Comment: I did go through the User guide and Source code you mentioned, but our sever is running in unmanaged mode. Was not aware of the fact that there are managed and unmanaged modes existing for the KIE server earlier. 
However, 
[PUT] /kie-server/services/rest/server/containers//{ContainerId}

with input payload is working fine for starting the container in unmanaged mode.

[DELETE] /kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/{ContainerId}

is working fine for stopping the container.

Left out with Upgrading the container now.

Comment: You can basically update the container in two different ways. You can either create a KIE scanner which will automatically update the container if the Maven artifact changes or you can change release ID in your container to use an artifact with different version. See the [REST calls](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html-single/User_Guide/index.html#idp10083952) you can make on unmanaged KIE Server.

Comment: You can also use Java client with [this interface](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/6.4.x/kie-server-parent/kie-server-remote/kie-server-client/src/main/java/org/kie/server/client/KieServicesClient.java). I have noticed that the method for updating release ID is missing in the documentation so you need to look at the [implementation](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/6.4.x/kie-server-parent/kie-server-remote/kie-server-client/src/main/java/org/kie/server/client/impl/KieServicesClientImpl.java#L216) if you want to call the REST endpoint directly.

Comment: Ok got it. I am also looking for REST calls for only uploading the artifact (Authoring tab -> Artifact Repository -> Upload project jar) into repository. This is just a dependency jar for our project and we need not have it under Deploy -> Process deployments.

If we do /business-central/rest/repositories/{repositoryName}/projects/{projectName}/maven/deploy/ REST call, it would reflect under Deploy -> Process as well, but this is not required for our project.